# Message queue is giving me an invalid argument

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble with my code. It should create a message queue and send a message, than wait some time for another program to receive that message and answer. The problem is, when I run it, I get an invalid argument both on the msgsnd and on the msgrcv.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

typedef struct my_msg{
    long type;
    char text[100];
    char sqdr;
}message;

static void score(int messagge_id, char* A_B){
    message send;
    send.type=1;
    strcpy(send.text, "Try to score");
    send.sqdr = *A_B;
    if((msgsnd(messagge_id, &send, sizeof(send), 0))<0)perror("Error msgsnd\n");
    sleep(3);
    if((msgrcv(messagge_id, &send, sizeof(send), 4, 0))==-1)perror("Error msgrcv 1\n");
    int test=atoi(send.text);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}


int main(){
    int caso, key;
    char team= 'A';
    key=1234;
    int msg_id=msgget(key, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    printf("Try function score\n");
    score(msg_id, &team);
    printf("After score\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you error check the `msgget()` call?  Does it succeed?  Has another process created the message queue?

Comment: I'll try checking the msgget, but I don't think the problem is for the creation of the message queue, since I didn't write the second program yet. Can it be a problem of the key used?

Comment: I think it is most likely a problem that you did not use either the key `IPC_PRIVATE` or specify `IPC_CREAT` as a flag (along with `S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR`), so you didn't attach to a pre-existing message queue and didn't create it either.  See [`msgget()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgget.html) (and 
[`msgctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgctl.html) to remove the message queue after you're done).  Note that once the queue is created, it remains in existence until deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the message queue is created.  You either use the key `IPC_PRIVATE` or you add `IPC_CREAT` to the flags.  You also need to try to read the message correctly.  You sent a 'type 1' message and attempted to read a 'type 4' message, so the read hangs.

This code also removes the message queue.  That's not critical if it is a private queue (such queues are deleted when the program terminates), but it is important for queues using `IPC_CREAT` and a user-defined key.  (I also changed the message text so that `atoi()` returned something more interesting — and convincing — than zero.  The code also uses separate send and receive buffers so that we know the code is not cheating and reusing data already in the buffer.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct my_msg
{
    long type;
    char text[100];
    char sqdr;
} message;

static void score(int messagge_id)
{
    message send;
    message recv;
    send.type = 1;
    strcpy(send.text, "47 tries to score");
    send.sqdr = 'A';
    if ((msgsnd(messagge_id, &send, sizeof(send), 0)) < 0)
        perror("Error msgsnd");
    printf("Dozing...\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("Unslumbering...\n");
    if ((msgrcv(messagge_id, &recv, sizeof(recv), -4, 0)) == -1)
        perror("Error msgrcv");
    int test = atoi(recv.text);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}

int main(void)
{
    int key = 1234;
    int flags = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|IPC_CREAT;
    // int key = IPC_PRIVATE;
    // int flags = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR;
    int msg_id = msgget(key, flags);
    if (msg_id < 0)
        perror("Error msgget");
    else
    {
        printf("Try function score\n");
        score(msg_id);
        printf("After score\n");
        if (msgctl(msg_id, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0)
            perror("Error msgctl");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Try function score
Dozing...
Unslumbering...
47
After score
```

There's a 3 second pause between 'Dozing' and 'Unslumbering', of course.

Answer (score -1):

use like this:-

```
if((msgsnd(messagge_id, (void *)&send, sizeof(send), 0))<0)perror("Error msgsnd\n");

if((msgrcv(messagge_id, (void *)&send, sizeof(send), 4, 0))==-1)perror("Error msgrcv 1\n");
```

Comment: What's the significant change?  The cast to `void *` is immaterial; it changes nothing.

Comment: The output is "Try function score. Error msgsnd: invalid argument. Error msgrcv: invalid argument. After score".